# Advice needed about tags

Tags: php, mysql, tags

I just need some advice about using tags. I'm working on a website right now and the users can post videos, images, audio and information about themselves.

I never worked with tags before on a normal website (did work with them on wordpress, youtube etc..), so I need some advise to start designing my database.

What is the common way to work with tags when you have multiple categories? Do I have to add tags for each category?
Example:

```
Table:
gallery

gallery_id
image
tags

Table
audio

audio_id
title
link
audio_tags

Etc...
```

Or do I make only one table named "tags" and all the tags in it?
Like:
Table Tags:

```
tag_id
tag
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends if you want tags to be shared among multiple objects. If you want that to be separate, then i would make separate tag tables for them. If not, I would have the same tag table, and use different tables for each relation the tags will have, so

for separate:

```
gallery
...
gallery_tags
tag_id
tag

tags_to_gallery
tag_id
gallery_id
..same for audio..
```

for not separate:

```
  gallery
  ...
  audio
  ...
  tags
    tag_id
    tag

  gallery_to_tag
  gallery_id
  tag_id

  audio_to_tag
  audio_id
  tag_id
```

you could also do this with one ploymorphic table. with a table with something like this:

```
tag_relations
 tag_id
 object_id
 object_table
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I'll go for separate tags for each category or else it will be a mess.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

It is up to you how you need to shape the application. If you want tags to be shared between galleries and audio, use a single table and two many-to-many reference tables (or one with polymorphism).

Comment: Thank you! I think I'll go for separate tags for each category. :)

Answer (score 0):

Technically the best format is the one you described first, but if you were going to implement the second you would need an extra field - that is the category field. But it would be better and easier to simple have tag fields in each table - better for readability and also use when you come to implement it in your site.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The certainly helps. Thank you very much for your help.